# Can I condense these values with a loop?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I have a set of values that get modified like so:

```
iskDropped = irrelevant1
iskDestroyed = irrelevant2
iskTotal = irrelevant3

iskDropped = condense_value(int(iskDropped[:-7].replace(',','')))
iskDestroyed = condense_value(int(iskDestroyed[:-7].replace(',','')))
iskTotal = condense_value(int(iskTotal[:-7].replace(',','')))
```

As you can see, all three lines go through the same changes. (condensed, shortened, and commas removed) before overwriting their original value.

I want to condense those three lines if possible because it feels inefficient.

I was trying something like this:

```
for value in [iskDropped,iskDestroyed,iskTotal]:
    value = condense_value(int(value[:-7].replace(',','')))
```

which if you changed into a print statement successfully does print the correct values but it does not work in the regard of overwriting / updating the values (iskDropped,iskDestroyed, and iskTotal) that I need to call later in the program.

Is it possible to condense these lines in Python? If so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
iskDropped, iskDestroyed, iskTotal = [condense_value(int(value[:-7].replace(',',''))) for value in [iskDropped, iskDestroyed, iskTotal]]
```

This works by looping through the list of your 3 variables, performing the `condense_value` function on each and creates a list of the results, then finally unpacks the list back into the original values.